# Team Foundation Build Error

Tags: tfsbuild, flyway

When I create a pull request for our database project and add a new file (we use flyway to manage the updates to the database), we keep getting the error in the build:

TF401174: The Item "XXX" could not be found in the repository 'Database' at the version specified by '' (resolved to commit 'xxxxx')

I am looking on our TFS site and cannot track down this exact problem.  When I look in our database repository at the location specified in the repository and the files are there 8 files that show this error.  I checked them all and they are present in the repository as I said.  Anyone have any suggestions?  I need to get a green build on the database again and need to solve this problem.  I am at a loss.

Thank you, your time and efforts are appreciated.

john

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem.  In the DB Project within Visual Studio it was having problems with the ALTER statement on the objects and the check to see if the object exists code.  Remove that code and changing the ALTER to CREATE fixed the problem this was because the objects were set to Build on the Build Action.  It has been said if you change it to NONE this error will also disappear.  Made the changes and did a recompile and it works.

Here is the error I got in my output window during compile: SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.